# Is there a cleaner way to return a promise of a promise using angular

Tags: angularjs, promise

I had the following code in my project and I was hoping it worked.

```
var retrieveUpdates = function (hash) {
    myFunction(data)
      .then(function(filters){
        return Restangular.all('retrieveUpdates').post({ filters });
    });
};
```

But of course this fails because a return is happening before the then. I can "fix" it but it seems to be ugly (especially when this scenario is all over the place).

```
var retrieveUpdates = function (hash) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    myFunction(data)
      .then(function(filters){
        Restangular.all('retrieveUpdates').post({ filters }).then(defer.resolve, defer.reject);
      });
    return defer.promise;
};
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just stick with what you have in the first place. It returns a promise so just chain off it for resolution callbacks? You can even do this in the service if you want and update a scope from there.

Comment: Related [What is the deferred anti-pattern and how do I avoid it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning anything in your first example, just return `myFunction`

```
var retrieveUpdates = function (hash) {
    return myFunction(data)
      .then(function(filters){
        return Restangular.all('retrieveUpdates').post({ filters });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var retrieveUpdates = function (hash) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
        myFunction(data)
          .then(function(filters){
              return Restangular.all('retrieveUpdates').post({ filters }).then(resolve, reject);
           });
    });     
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var retrieveUpdates = function (hash) {
    return myFunction(data)
      .then(function(filters){
         return Restangular.all('retrieveUpdates').post({ filters });
      });
 };
```

that is the common patter for promises, a promise, always returns a promise